# Solve $\int\ 3x\cos(2x)dx$ with integration by parts

Tags: calculus, integration

I have this problem here that is asking for me to use Integration by Parts.

I solved it out but it seems as if it can be an ongoing function. I was told you can work with it if the second time you integrate by parts it will be similar to the original integral but I don't see how to get it.

[image]

My answer after doing integration by parts twice was:

$$\int\ 3x\cos(2x)dx=\frac{3x}{2}\sin(2x)+\frac{3}{4}\cos(2x)-\int\frac{-1}{2}\cos(2x)dx$$

Any help on figuring out what to do from here would be very grateful thank you.

Comment: Simply integrate $\int -1/2\cos(2x)dx=-1/4\sin(2x)$ But i think you only have to do integration by parts one time.

Answer (score 1):

Only one application is necessary; letting $u = 3x$ and $dv = \cos 2x dx$, so that $du = 3 dx$ and $v = \frac 1 2 \sin 2x$, we find that

$$\int 3x \cos(2x) dx = \frac{3x}{2} \sin 2x - \frac 3 2 \int \sin 2x dx$$

Now can you find the antiderivative of $\sin 2x$?

Comment: I forgot to take the 3/2 out of the second integral... Silly mistake. Got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you obtained,
$$-\int\frac{-1}{2}cos(2x)dx=\int\frac{1}{2}cos(2x)dx=\int\frac{1}{4}cos(2x)d(2x)=\frac{1}{4}\sin(2x)+C$$